# Unable to set PK of EF code-first class

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have a `Device` class whose primary key is its serial number ala:

```
public class Device
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Device serial number
    /// </summary>
    [Key]
    public int Serial { get; set; }
}
```

For some reason Entity Framework wont actually let me set the primary key when I first create this class.  It instead creates its own number for `Serial`.  What am I missing?

```
context.Devices.AddOrUpdate(new Device()
{
    Serial = 89484848 // never gets set, EF sets its own PK
});
```

Comment: have you tried the attribute `DatabaseGenerated` with the value DatabaseGeneratedOption.None ?

Comment: Yes, initially I got an error but after deleting my database it works now! How would I do this with an upgrade (where data loss is not permitted?)

Comment: you have to use sql statements to : create a new column of type Int (newSerial), update the new column with the serial values (newSerial = Serial), drop serial column, then rename newSerial to Serial. This should be a little more complicated with FK constraints on Serial.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set key as **DeviceId** or **Id** not Serial (which is diffrent from table name)

You can take a look on this link [msdn blog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/data/jj591583.aspx#Key) entry